# Jquery not working after precompile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

An image was causing a problem on my heroku app so I changed `config.assets.compile = false` to `config.assets.compile = true` in production.rb. I then ran `rake assets:precompile` and pushed to the heroku server. Jquery works fine on the app website, but no longer works on my local copy. No errors are thrown in the javascript console. Here are some important files as they stand now.

Production.rb

```
Nonogrammed::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery.ui.mouse
//= require jquery.ui.draggable
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .


$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ handle: "#handle" , containment: [0,0,1200,1000] , cursor: "crosshair" });
  });
```

UPDATE: This was caused by deleting an image , making a new image with the same name, and then pushing to heroku. Don't do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to precompile on your local. Sprockets automatically compiles static asset at server start.

To resolve things, delete the compiled files in the `public/assets` directory, commit your changes, then deploy to Heroku again.

Then, *in Heroku*, compile your assets by running the following from your command line:

```
# from command line via the Heroku Toolbelt
rake run assets:precompile
```

Your local assets will compile on server start (thus rendering jQuery usable again), and your assets on Heroku will be precompiled to the `public/assets` directory as they should be.

**UPDATE**:

You may need to clear your browser cache to ensure that the updated asset path is loaded into your markup.

Comment: I don't see any compiled files in the app/assets directory, are they hidden?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `public/assets`. I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: After I delete the compiled files, and reset the server, should jquery work? Because it's not. Maybe i'm not deleting all the compiled files?

Comment: It should... have you verified whether the import tag is correctly importing jQuery in your HTML `<head>`?

Comment: I ended up doing a hard rollback, and jquery is still not working on my local machine. This is driving me insane

Comment: Figured it out, just had to delete cache on my browser. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If this answer helped, would you consider accepting it as correct? Also, I've updated my answer to reflect your comment regarding clearing the browser cache.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38515/discussion-between-vigrant-and-zeantsoi)